# Constructing zero matrix in apache commons library in java

Tags: java, apache, apache-commons

I have been scavenging thru the documentation of apache common core math library to search for this answer but havent been able to find the answer.. 
http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-math/apidocs/org/apache/commons/math4/linear/RealMatrix.html

How do we construct or initialize a matrix with default value.

So, I see we can do this

```
RealMatrix X = new BlockRealMatrix(numRows, numCols);
   or 
  double[][] matrixData = { {1d,2d,3d}, {2d,5d,3d}};
 RealMatrix m = MatrixUtils.createRealMatrix(matrixData);
```

But how do i construct a matrix and initialize it to all (say) 2.. (or 0 in my case), rather than explicitly creating the `double[][]`

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no single method that sets all values to a certain default value. In order to initialize the Matrix various methods might be used which all require iterating through the dimensions. `setColumn` and `setRow` allow setting the values of the entire column or row which might come close to what is searched for.